# Time between checkins

Tags: api, foursquare, checkin

If I make two sequential checkins in a venue, Foursquare venues API won't count the second check-in. How long (minutes) the API will count the new check-in as a new number? There is something about it anywhere in documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The API will only allow you to check in to the same place once every three hours.